# How to group headers and footers in SQL Server with GROUPING BY?

Tags: sql-server

I have looked up similar references but still couldn't find the solution.

I have three columns: Class, UPC, Price.

Values for Class: A, B, C

Values for UPC: A001, A002, A003, B001, B002, B003, C001, C002, C003.

I need to use the GROUPING BY as I need to show price totals.

What I am looking for:

```
| --Class-- | --UPC-- | --Price--|
      A        
                A001      $1.15
                A002      $4.45
                A003      $1.75
      A                   $7.35

      B        
                B001      $2.00
                B002      $4.00
                B003      $3.00
      B                   $9.00

      C        
                C001      $10.00
                C002      $20.00
                C003      $30.00
      C                   $60.00
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a result that's better suited for a reporting tool/presentation layer rather than SQL Server

Comment: [Using GROUP BY with ROLLUP, CUBE, and GROUPING SETS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/ue-en/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Can you include some sample input?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Class, UPS, sum(Price) price from table group by Class,UPS WITH CUBE
```